# Does millionth have a commonly used sign like % (percentage)?

Tags: notation

Does millionth have a commonly used sign like % (percentage)? I tried to check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_sign), but not found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When describing millionths of something, we add "ppm" (which stands for [parts per million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts-per_notation)) at the end of a quantity to say that it is in millionths. For example, 0.1% is equivalent to 1000ppm or 0.001.